# labeling relationship lines in mysql workbench erd

Tags: entity-relationship, mysql-workbench

I'm not really sure if ERD is the proper term, but occasionally I see diagrams created where the line in between two entities is labeled with text to describe the relationship.

For example if I had `User`, `Item`, `ItemRating`, I may want to describe the line between `User` and `ItemRating` as "rates" and the line between `Item` and `ItemRating` as "is rated by".

[image]

I found I can make a text object in mysql workbench, and place it where I want, but I can't find a way to attach it to a line so that it moves with the line if I rearrange things.

using mysql workbench 5.2.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to do the same thing but haven't found a way. I don't think it can be done in Workbench. I'm using 5.2.34.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same question before exploring the menu

On MySqlWorkbench, while EER diagram Is open :

Menu> Model > model Options > Diagram

untick 'use defaults' and untick 'hide captions'

You Can now See the relation caption, but it Can get Messy if You write a 2nd capt.

Answer (score 0):

Check this it may answer your query.

> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-using-text-object-tool.html